# How can I create a typescript interface for a list of variables with similar names?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to declare an interface that has many variables with similar name and I don't want to create it manually. The type is like

```
interface {
  "Var 1": string;
  "Var 2": string;
  "Var 3": string;
  "Var 4": string;
  "Var 5": string;
}
```

This list can go upto 55 so it isn't feasible to write all the variable names in the interface.

Comment: Why do you need an interface like this in the first place? Sounds like you should be using an array.

Comment: There is a use case where I have to use this kind of structure. I am using the data for exporting an array of this interface to csv etc. So I have to specify the column names in this format.

Comment: I am also using other types in the interface so I cannot use `[key: string]: string`

Comment: I've used `[key: string]: string | number;` for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to turn a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of numeric types into keys of the sort you are looking for.  Let's say you have a type named `VarRange` of the following form:

```
type VarRange = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 
  | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20
  | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 
  | 31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35 | 36 | 37 | 38 | 39 | 40
  | 41 | 42 | 43 | 44 | 45 | 46 | 47 | 48 | 49 | 50 
  | 51 | 52 | 53 | 54 | 55
```

Then you can write your interface as

```
interface VarInterface extends Record<`Var ${VarRange}`, string> { }
```

And verify that it works as expected

```
declare const vi: VarInterface;
vi["Var 51"] = "okay"
vi["Var 99"]; // error
```

---

Unfortunately there is no built-in method to easily create `VarRange`; it would be nice if you could write `type VarRange = 1 .. 55`, but TypeScript does not support such things as of TypeScript 4.4.  There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#15480](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480) to implement range types like this, but for now it does not exist.

So either you could use the hardcoded list like I have above, or you could write some more complicated type manipulation to make the compiler try to figure it out for you. In TypeScript 4.5 they will [lift some recursion restrictions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5-beta/#tailrec-conditional) in the language and you'll be able to do this:

```
type TupleOf<N extends number, T = any, R extends T[] = []> =
  R['length'] extends N ? R : TupleOf<N, T, [T, ...R]>

type VarRange = Exclude<keyof TupleOf<56>, "0" | keyof any[]>
/* type VarRange = "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9" | "10" |
 "11" | "12" | "13" | "14" | "15" | "16" | "17" | "18" | "19" | "20" | "21" |
 "22" | "23" | "24" | "25" | "26" | "27" | "28" | "29" | ... 25 more ... | "55" */

interface VarInterface extends Record<`Var ${VarRange}`, string> { }
```

which uses [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) and  [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to build up a tuple of length `56`, and grab all the numeric-like keys of it (excluding `"0"`).

---

For TS4.1 through TS4.4 you could still do it but it's even more complicated, since the recursion limits are too shallow to reach `55`.  Maybe something like:

```
type Length7 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
type Length14 = [...Length7, ...Length7];
type Length28 = [...Length14, ...Length14];
type Length56 = [...Length28, ...Length28];

type VarRange = Exclude<keyof Length56, "0" | keyof any[]>
/* type VarRange = "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9" | "10" |
 "11" | "12" | "13" | "14" | "15" | "16" | "17" | "18" | "19" | "20" | "21" |
 "22" | "23" | "24" | "25" | "26" | "27" | "28" | "29" | ... 25 more ... | "55" */

interface VarInterface extends Record<`Var ${VarRange}`, string> { }
```

---

But I don't know if either of these are worth it to you. At some point, maintaining a hardcoded list of numbers or strings is easier than maintaining complex type manipulation code.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlkAiANTimQEYyAuZAZzClAHMBuE8qmgEyMWbTj1KVqyAMzDW7EN16SaAFjmjF4vlICsGhUoC+RIgHozyABZgwAB2YMLHYGCsBXAEYA6BAHsAWzMA4AQoP2Y-GDAzABV0OwgAZTDgOxjgZmZ3CGYzWl1VAA4ABlMwBJR+ACU4RRQAXjpkAB9kAVaZTtVO3U6ANk6Adk6izoBOTtoSqdopjrbaaSmexb7FwcWRxbHFybaBMtIDuYOF9uWD1fb19s327fbd9v2ZGbbpU5lz6UuZa+kt2k92kj2kz2kr1UR26X1U51Uf1U11Ut1U91Uj2K3VeuneyF0X10510f0KvV0plAkFgiCq1GwNLwKAgAA9ICAACbMZDVCD+KCcgA8AAN+MgACQEGp1DgQIwigA0IkMAD5CMgTEROfyADbUFD+ECsZAAN2ATH4jNwdJ45oA2ioCfQALrIJpkPwAazg6DIRAdTvG4zILq4yAsyGg4SgphAcACuTsdOQsSSqMIplIFUSqfcdl1EAA8jAhQA5KPsiBcnkgdwBTzQZWxd3IOroZXVSsc7mp+1upr99UNXikar2gDkhcUbgnbrZPZ5FYA-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-ImZ54o+dQ0PykqKpBRqWqkOF+qmVFfjGmAZoWqh8Wq0gSXAI6KWuul3q+v6pA5TQeVhhGlhFbGphGEAA)